# Add Object to the end of a JSON File when Electron app restarts

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a text field where you can enter the description of a task that needs to be done. When you click the "Add" button, it add the unique ID and the task to the JSON file in the form as an object. This works fine as an Electron app. However, when the app restarts, it overwrites the current JSON code that is already there. I need it to append the Objects to the end of the JSON file when the Electron app is restarted. How would I do this?

Here is the JavaScript Code:

```
// This is the counter
var indentification = 0;

// This is the submit button
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");

// This is the text field
var content = document.getElementById("text");

var task = {
    list: []
}

submit.onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    id = indentification++;
    description = content.value;

    task.list.push({id, description})
    jsonifyTask = JSON.stringify(task);
    disk.writeFile("tasks.json", jsonifyTask, "utf8")
}
```

How could I fix this? Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Where is this json file located? Does it return to its initial state every time, or do you only see the last task you entered after saving?

Comment: When the app restarts, the JSON file is still intact. When the user clicks the button to add a task, the JSON file goes back to: { }. With nothing in it.

Comment: Because you never read previously saved json file?

Comment: @dfsq That would be my guess too

Comment: I tried the disk.readFile() (I called the FS module disk) function, but when I put it in the onclick function, it made a duplicate. When I removed it out of the function, it didn't do anything.

Comment: @dfsq Actually, I don't think I previously saved the file. Would'nt fs.writeFile() do it? I tried fs.appendFile(), but it never cleared what was in the JSON file already, just dumping new content in there. What should I do?